# Unable to pass variable value from QMainWindow to QDialog in Qt5.4

Tags: qt5.4

I would like to pass the values of variable or in other words, i would like initialize the variables of Dialog class in MainWindow and execute Dialog window. I can successfully initialize the variables of Dialog class using constructor. But when I try to initialize the private or public variables using the defined public function in Dialog class, it doesn't work. Please see below code:

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:


    explicit Dialog(const QString &d, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    void setDat(const QString &k);



private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

    QString msg;

    QString msg2;

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(const QString &d, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    msg = d;

    ui->label->setText(msg);

    ui->label_2->setText(msg2);
}

void Dialog::setDat(const QString &k)
{
    msg2 = k;
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "dialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString temp = "Hello....";
    Dialog dg(temp);
    dg.setDat(temp);
    dg.exec();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean saying `it doesn't work`? No output is shown to us.

Comment: I meant that the setText property of  label and label_2 is not assigned during the form load which in this case is the constructor. But now i understood that the constructor function of Dialog class is executed when object is created. That's the reason why the labels' setText property is not set. I thought the constructor function is executed when the dialog form is loaded or run after dg.exec()

Comment: It's fine now.. I got the solution.

Comment: you should post it as an answer and make it best to close it.